# how to send data from a form that has multiples components on its own?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I want to send the data from the inputs, and the radio buttons.

But the problem is on my home page, the inputs and the radio buttons are different components, but wrapped in a form.

I can't still get the button to work, should I not have made them separate components? or is there a way to send data from a form with multiples components ?

can you guide me towards the right direction on how to send the  data  to the api from the form? thank you

```js
<template>
  <div class="home ">
    <app-header/>
    <div class="justify-center flex">
    <!-- the left side -->
    <div class=" mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 pl-28 pt-24">
      <h1 class="font-Poppins font-bold text-4xl tracking-wide ml-4 mb-8">
        Homiy sifatida ariza topshirish
      </h1>
      <!-- tabs -->
      <ul class="flex flex-wrap max-w-xl pl-5 ">
        <li class="flex-auto text-center">
          <a class=" block rounded py-3 transition font-Rubik uppercase text-xs
              font-medium text-center tracking-wider w-full "
               :class="{
                  'hover:text-white text-white bg-bgblue': tab === 'Jismoniy',
                  'hover:text-blue-600 ': tab === 'Yuridik',
                }"
            href="#"
             @click.prevent="tab = 'Jismoniy'"
            >Jismoniy shaxs</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="flex-auto text-center mr-4">
          <a class=" block rounded py-3 transition font-Rubik uppercase
              text-xs font-medium text-center tracking-wider ml-4 w-full"
            :class="{
                  'hover:text-white text-white bg-bgblue': tab === 'Yuridik',
                  'hover:text-blue-600': tab === 'Jismoniy',
                }"
            href="#"
            @click.prevent="tab = 'Yuridik'"
            >Yuridik shaxs</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="forms max-w-xl ">
        <Jismoniy v-show="tab ==='Jismoniy'" />
        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <Yuridik v-show="tab === 'Yuridik'"/>
        <Tolov/>
        <my-button @submit.prevent="send" class="mx-4">
          Yuboring
        </my-button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Jismoniy from '@/components/Jismoniy.vue'
import Yuridik from '@/components/Yuridik.vue'
import Tolov from '@/components/Tolov.vue'
import AppHeader from '@/components/Header.vue'
import MyButton from '@/components/UI/MyButton.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data(){
    return{
      tab: 'Jismoniy'
    }
  },
  components: { 
    Jismoniy, 
    Yuridik, 
    Tolov,
    AppHeader,
    MyButton 
    },
  methods:{
    send(){
      console.log('send worked');
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will be helpfull: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/03/31/vue-js-form-composition-api/

Comment: @Nechoj unfortunately no, I guess I will have to write it all on the home page, because, that is how I know so far, perhaps  there are other ways, but nothing I know by myself for now.